# What would be the opposite of onclick="myFunction()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, display

**NOT A DUPLICATE** because I'm asking for an `"offclick"` event (if any) for the purpose of hiding an element, not how to hide the element.

I have a container with **`display: none;`** that it's only shown when clicking on a `<textarea>` tag by using **`onclick="myFunction()"`**. However, I'd like to set the container back to **`display: none;`** once it is clicked outside the `<textarea>`.

Is there any `offclick` equivalent for this?

```
  function myFunction() {
  $('.testing').css({
    display: 'inline-block'
  });
}
```

```
.testing {
  display: none;
}
```

```
<div>
  <textarea onclick="myFunction()" placeholder="Write something..."></textarea>
</div>
<div class="testing"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: there is no Html element with `onclick=“myFunction()”` please show us

Comment: I think OP is looking for onfocusout: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp

Comment: @Michael this is exactly it! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you will have to look into onMouseUp event.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use **onblur** attribute within your html tag and give it the function from your javascript.
For example, here i have an input, and when i click and write stuff there, the background color of the input changes to green, but when i click outside the input, the background color changes back to white.
Hope this helped. ^^

```html
<input type="text" onclick="makeBackgroundColorGreen()" onblur="resetBackgroundColortoWhite">
```

Comment: read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a listener at the window level and then hide it depending on whether the click was made outside the textarea (target), but only if the textarea is visible, otherwise it would be pointless making the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is(".testing")) {
        $(".testing").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: this makes "myFunction()" lose effect when clicking on the textarea tag

Comment: My function is only for hide after click outside textarea. For show texarea use your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    menu.onclick = () =>{
  menu.classList.add('fa-times');
  navbar.classList.add('active');
}

    enter code here

window.onscroll = () =>{
  menu.classList.remove('fa-times');
  navbar.classList.remove('active');
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.